# Align Chart JS Y-Axis dot with X-Axis value

Tags: chart.js

Is there a way to align vertically the dot with the x-axis value? I'm using chart.js v2.5.0. I know that behaviour only happens when there's just one dataset pair [x,y].[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a Fiddle or something like that we might be able to give something more concrete, but you can achieve this by setting the `min` property on the axes.

Something like that

```
let options = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                min: <insert value here>,
            }
        }]
    }
};
```